# Let $u \in \mathbb{Z}^{\times}_{p}$ a unit, is it true that the field $\mathbb{Q}_{p}(\zeta_{p^{n}}, \sqrt[p^{n}]{u})$  is abelian over  $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$? 

Tags: p-adic, fields

Let $u \in \mathbb{Z}^{\times}_{p}$ a unit, is it true that the
field $\mathbb{Q}_{p}(\zeta_{p^{n}}, \sqrt[p^{n}]{u})$ `
is abelian over  $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$?

Comment: First try the case $n=1$.  Try to find a criterion for a degree-$p$ cyclic extension $L$ of $K={\mathbf Q}_p(\zeta_p)$ to be galoisian (resp. abelian) over $F={\mathbf Q}_p$, or extract such a criterion from Section 4 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2016.

Comment: Any subextension of an abelian extension is Galois. Now try to find a non-Galois subextension in your case (with $u$ not being a $p^n$th power).

Comment: It is simpler in your situation to consult Section 2 of http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2829.

Comment: References to the literature seem like overkill. This question needs nothing but Galois theory and basic properties of $p$-adic fields.